# How to enable virtual keyboard on macOS Catalina login?

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, accessibility

I can not login and work on my mac. macOS seems to switch keyboard layouts on login for me on macOS Catalina.

After I log in, my keyboard layout changes to the correct one. 
I need the keyboard shortcut to activate the virtual keyboard on login.

An alternate solution would be the keyboard shortcut to switch users by typing the new username. This way I can see which keyboard layout is selected in order to find the correct keyboard shortcut for my password chars.

Comment: To be able to change your keyboard layout on the login screen, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202036  To activate the accessibility keyboard, see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-accessibility-options-login-window-mchlaa57f797/mac

Comment: A very sad state of macOS Crapalina and Apple